# how to convert to import/export module's syntax by TypeScript global module

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I want to convert older project's typescript code, for example:

```
// dataService.ts
module ProjectNs.Models {
    export class DataService {
        props1: string;

        constructor(
            private service: ProjectNs.Service.MyInjectService
        ) { }
    } 
}
```

it's equal global variable's method. now, I want to use webpack, and like es6 module syntax. for example:

```
// dataService.ts
export class DataService {
    props1: string;

    constructor(
        private service: ProjectNs.Service.MyInjectService
    ) { }
}

// main.ts

import {DataService} from './dataService';

class Main {

}
```

There are so many TypeScript File, so, Is there any tool for batch conversion?

Comment: a tool no, but maybe you can use a well crafted regex replacement? :)

Comment: ...thanks, it's not simple string replace, may be no a tool...